# Angular zone.js and shim.min.js error

Tags: node.js, angular

I have downloaded the angular quick start code and set it up in my machine but when i run the command npm start it gives me the following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded.
    at zone.js:32
    at zone.js:643
    at FUNCTION (zone.js:11)
    at zone.js:12

Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function
    at new NgZone (core.umd.js:3807)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (core.umd.js:4524)
    at eval (core.umd.js:4569)
    at shim.min.js:8
    at shim.min.js:8
    at MutationObserver.s (shim.min.js:7)
    at Zone.run (angular2-polyfills.js:138)
    at MutationObserver.zoneBoundFn (angular2-polyfills.js:111)
```

I am using node version 6.11.3 and npm version as 3.10.10. So can anybody help me on this?

Comment: I am not using angular-cli instead i have downloaded the code from git for quick-start app then i have followed whatever the commands that guide provided. This is the guide https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: @nivas: When i remove the zone.js file path from the index.html then i am getting the 2nd error which i mentioned in my original post above.